# On push, I receive a "overwritten by merge" error. I believe it is caused by a post-update hook. Can I bypass?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I have a certain file, `filename.html`, that I've made some changes to and I'd like to push the commit.  So I've made changes, added and committed them.  Whenever I push, I get the following output:

`Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 439 bytes | 439.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: **** Pulling changes into Live [Hub's post-update hook]
remote:
remote: From /var/git/html
remote:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
remote: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
remote:         filename.html
remote: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
remote: Aborting
remote: Updating c987b05..583872c
To website.com:/var/git/html.git
   76ad8aa..583872c  master -> master`

I've tried to `git reset --hard` and I've tried to force a push.  I tried `git push origin master --no-verify`. I've tried to stash the changes. No success.

To be clear, I can make changes and push commits just fine for all other files in the project.  It is just this one particular file that, if I make and commit changes to, won't let me push.

From another question I've asked here, I've been told that it's probably the post-update hook that is causing a pull and this is where the error arises. However, I haven't been able to find a way around it. I didn't set up the git on this project, and the developer that did has since left the company.  The git is set up in a way that, when pushed, the changes are pushed via ftp to update the dev site.

Is there a way to bypass this hook so I can push? Is there a better fix to this problem I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance, this one has me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so after a lot of research and trial and error I finally fixed it.  Essentially the git was set up to update a dev site when you do a `git push`.  This system is basically set up along the same lines as the one described [here](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/)

So what I did is I replaced the original post update hook, which is the one described in the linked article, with this:

`#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "**** Pulling changes into Live [Hub's post-update hook]"
echo
cd /var/www/html || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git fetch --all
git reset --hard hub/master
git pull hub master
exec git-update-server-info`

After this I was finally able to get past the error outlined in the original post, and now everything is running smoothly again.